# How to create a jquery image slider with css animated elements inside?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, carousel

My client wants me to create an image slider(carousel) for their website. They want the slides to actually 'slide' and not fade in or anything and also want the content inside of it to fade in and fade out. Pretty much exactly like this: http://www.squarespace.com/

Now I tried searching a lot for jquery plugins and tutorials on how to create something like this and I found few, mostly on codrops, but none that I can work with and that fits the criteria. I also found Flexslider, but in that I just can't figure out how I will create animation for the content inside using css3 transitions or keyframes. Again exactly like Squarespace that I linked.

Please let me know regarding this and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best sliders i know of: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#&panel1-1.

He has also done a tutorial on making one yourself : http://css-tricks.com/slider-with-sliding-backgrounds/, which you could use as a starting point for making your own

Answer (score 0):

Why reinventing the wheel? there are tons of image-slider carousels. even with 'slide effects'

Here's exactly the slider you're searching for :)

https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides

A demo page can be found here:

http://nicinabox.com/superslides/#1

Hope it helps.

ps: google is your friend.

EDIT: From your comment about, fading content in the slider.

I guess (not tested) you can just add a transition to the content when fading, you can easily add this to the css or js of the slider.

Comment: This is just fantastic and the closest one to what I want. But the problem is that I do not know how to apply animations to the content inside of each slide. For example, when the use clicks the next button, how do I fade out the content of the sliding-out and fade in the content of the sliding-in slide?

May be what I'm asking is how can I give the current slide a class of 'current' and then when the user clicks the next button, how can I give this slide a class of 'slide-out' and the next slide to 'slide-in'. This way I can target the content of each slide of the two slides differently

Comment: I will look for this and will edit my code if I found it, firstly you could start to implement this slider into your website :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the prior answer

As far as fading out the content of the previous slide you could us a jQuery css selector for the element with a z-index of 2 as noted in this article:

"[30 CSS Selectors you must memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)"

And then set the opacity of the old one using a css3 transition, the new one I'm not entirely sure of.
However the superslides seem to be working directly off of the unordered list so you could use nth-of-type css selector to get the correct element via jQuery again using a js variable to store the correct slide number.

(this is for normal navigation only, the nav bar at the bottom would need some additional tinkering)

Answer (score 0):

I'm overly impressed with the link to 30 CSS Selectors you must memorize by Jonathan. Using those along with storing the slide number, you could pretty much do anything to Superslides. Love both tools guys. Probably one of the better tricks using jQuery and CSS I've read regarding sliding images. I'm playing around with cell padding and tables into this mix as well using Dreamweaver. Getting all this to play nicely with WordPress would be like...awesome sauce!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but is instead a comment on one of the other answers